# flex not growing in proportion to flex:

Tags: css, flexbox

I wish box1 to take about 50% of the screen and box2 to take up 25%.
So there could be 2x box1 on a line or 1x box1 and 2x box2 etc..
I can't seem to achieve this with any combination using flex-grow and flex-basis. I thought that for a given flex-basis, the ratio in flex-grow would take effect but it isn't for me. What I am doing wrong. I've had this problem for a while so I thought I'd try and get to the bottom of it.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.flex_container {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box1 {
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    background: red;    
    border: 1px solid blue;

/* flex: shorthand for flex-grow: flex-shrink: flex-basis: */
    flex: 2 0 47%;  
}

.box2 {
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 1%;
    background: blue;   
    border: 1px solid red;

/* flex: shorthand for flex-grow: flex-shrink: flex-basis: */
    flex: 1 0 47%;
}

<div class="flex_container">
    <div class="box1">
        Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim. 
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim. 
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
 Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim. 
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim. 
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim. 
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd just like to understand what the issue is. I'd like to get it like below. I can do it with set widths in different classes but not using flex: Thanks.

50%       50%

25% 25%   50%

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use rows here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
}
.box1 {
  padding: 1%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 2 0 50%;
}
.box2 {
  padding: 1%;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="box1">
    Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum
    nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim.
  </div>
  <div class="box1">
    Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum
    nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="box2">
    Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum
    nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim.
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum
    nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim.
  </div>
  <div class="box1">
    Nulla venenatis scelerisque porttitor. Proin maximus, arcu quis placerat auctor, sem metus commodo neque, at commodo augue neque quis elit. Curabitur id feugiat nunc, vitae rutrum erat. Fusce blandit ornare sem, rhoncus placerat mi placerat id. Vestibulum
    nec sollicitudin ex. Fusce sodales libero et ante ullamcorper consequat. Maecenas id condimentum libero, ac pretium enim.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I was hoping to use one row with wrap so in the next stage I can define a min-width so they all drop into a line at say 400px. i.e all would be 100%.

Comment: Not sure that's possible.